# Get latest entry from multiple entries for the same user from a table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. **Table A and Table B**.

Table A contains the details of individual users.

Table B contains 3 columns, namely **"is_completed", "user_id" and "work_id"**......

Table B tracks the details of work done by users and whether the work is completed or not. If completed, then that user can be assigned another work.

**Problem Statement :** 
I assigned a work to user 1 and his is_completed is 0 (work not finished)...now I assume that after some days, his work is finished, so I did is_completed as 1 but at the same time I assigned another work to the same user 1 and now is_completed is 0. So I have two rows of same user, one with is_completed as 1 and another is_completed as 0 in Table B.

**How can I fetch the latest is_completed i.e. user 1 as working or say busy?**

Comment: Can we assume that `work_id` will always increase?

Comment: Provide some same data and expected result out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.work_id) AS working FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    FROM TableB
    WHERE user_id = 1
    ORDER BY work_id DESC LIMIT 2;
) AS t
```

Result:

```
+---------+
| working |
+---------+
|    1    |   // not working
|    2    |   // working
+---------+
```

This query will return `2` if user 1 is currently in the middle of a task, indicating that there is only one record for the most recent `work_id`.  It will return `1` if the user has finished his previous task and has not yet received a new task, indicating two records (start and stop) for the most recent `work_id`.

I assume that the `work_id` which gets assigned is always increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select u.user_id, if(ifnull(w.is_completed, 0) = 1, 'Busy', 'Available') as Status
  from users u 
    left join work w 
      on u.user_id = w.user_id 
    left join work w2 
      on w.user_id = w2.user_id and w.work_id < w2.work_id
   where w2.work_id is null
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03aa7/9

Query will return ALL users and their current availability as either 'Busy' or 'Available', depending on the status of their most recent work entry.  Note this depends on the notion that work_id is an ascending, never repeating value, and that a work_id greater than another work_id, is guaranteed to be the more recent of the two.

If you want it to show the status for a specific user_id, just append `AND user_id = ??` to the above query

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.user_id,t.is_completed from( select * from
     TableB
    order by work_id desc )as t group by t.user_id
```

This will give latest work staus of a user